# AZURE blob storage v2 lifecycle management

Tags: azure, blob, lifecycle

I am preparing for DP-200 exam and confused with lifecycle management.
The sample scenario is:

You manage a financial computation data analysis process. Microsoft Azure virtual machines (VMs) run the process in daily jobs, and store the results in virtual hard drives (VHDs.)
The VMs product results using data from the previous day and store the results in a snapshot of the VHD. When a new month begins, a process creates a new
VHD.
You must implement the following data retention requirements:
- Daily results must be kept for 90 days
- Data for the current year must be available for weekly reports
- Data from the previous 10 years must be stored for auditing purposes
- Data required for an audit must be produced within 10 days of a request.
You need to enforce the data retention requirements while minimizing cost.
How should you configure the lifecycle policy? To answer, drag the appropriate JSON segments to the correct locations. Each JSON segment may be used once, more than once, or not at all. You may need to drag the split bat between panes or scroll to view content.

```
<code>"BaseBlob": {
"TierToArchive": { "DaysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 365 },
"Delete": { "DaysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 3650 }
},
"Snapshot": {
"TierToCool": {"DaysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 90 }
}</code>
```

That's the solution marked as correct. I try to find the "snapshot" documentation regarding lifecycle, but cannot find it in MS docs.

Can someone explain me the purpose of a Snapshot here please? and what correct lifecycle should be.

Answer (score 0):

--Daily results must be kept for 90 days
--Data for the current year must be available for weekly reports
--Data from the previous 10 years must be stored for auditing purposes
--Data required for an audit must be produced within 10 days of a request

baseblob
-- delete -10years
-- tiertocold -10days
-- tiertoarchive -1 years

snapshot
-- delete -90days

**Reference link for the snapshot**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=template#rules